# Is there a performant numpy or pandas method to create custom buckets?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there an efficient in python without using for loops, to create the following output? 
I have a dataframe including multiple items, dates and quantities and a specific lead time for each item. The goal is, to create a dataframe that sums up the quantities over the lead time days. 
In the example below, the first item has a lead time of 14 days, so on the 10.02.2020 the sum of quantities over the next 14 days is 6. On 11.02.2020 the sum will be 4 and so on. The problem is, that every item has its own lead time.
I have roughly 12.000 items with more than a year of demand, so I would like to avoid for loops to improve efficiency. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this using pandas, numpy or anything else?

**Data frame:**

```
item   date        quantity   lead_time
1      10.02.2020  2          14
1      12.02.2020  1          14
1      14.02.2020  3          14
...
2      10.02.2020  2          20
2      20.02.2020  2          20
2      02.03.2020  2          20
...
```

**Expected output:**

```
item   date       quantity
1      10.02.2020   6
1      11.02.2020   4
1      12.02.2020   4
1      13.02.2020   3
1      14.02.2020   3
1      15.02.2020   0
...
2      10.02.2020   4
2      11.02.2020   2
2      12.02.2020   2
2      13.02.2020   4
2      14.02.2020   4
2      15.02.2020   4
...
```

This is how I would solve it using a loop:

```
demand = pd.DataFrame({"item":["1","1","1","1","1"], "date":["2020-01-03", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-15", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-22"], "quantity":[1,1,1,1,1], "lead_time":[14,14,14,14,14]})
demand.date = pd.to_datetime(demand.date)
calendar = pd.DataFrame({"date":  pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-31', freq='d').strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))})
calendar.date = pd.to_datetime(calendar.date)
calendar = calendar.merge(demand, how='left')
calendar.lead_time = 14
calendar['cummulative_quantity'] = 0
calendar.quantity = calendar.quantity.fillna(0)

for i in range(len(calendar)):
    lead_time = calendar.loc[i, "lead_time"]
    calendar.loc[i, "cummulative_quantity"] = sum(calendar.loc[i:i+lead_time, "quantity"])
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this: "so on the 10.02.2020 the sum of quantities over the next 14 days is 6"?

Comment: Yes exactly, and on 11.02.2020 the sum over the next 14 days is 4

Comment: You have to explain your question better, like Dani said it's hard to follow what you mean.

Comment: I've added an example how I would do it using a loop, just for a single item. Hope that helps?

Comment: Define 'Performant' and 'efficiency'.  why do you think 'using for loops' would be a problem in your scenario?  What problems does your example give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion that is not completely loop-free but may work for you. As a sample frame `demand` I adapted the the first one of your examples:

```
   item       date  quantity  lead_time
0     1 2020-02-10         2         14
1     1 2020-02-12         1         14
2     1 2020-02-14         3         14
3     2 2020-02-10         2         20
4     2 2020-02-20         2         20
5     2 2020-03-02         2         20
```

This

```
dfs = []
for key, group in demand.groupby(['item', 'lead_time']):
    group = group.resample('D', on='date').first().fillna({'item': key[0], 'quantity': 0})
    group.quantity = group.quantity[::-1].rolling(f'{key[1]}d').sum()[::-1]
    dfs.append(group[['item', 'quantity']])
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis='index')
```

prdoduces the following result:

```
            item  quantity
date                      
2020-02-10   1.0       6.0
2020-02-11   1.0       4.0
2020-02-12   1.0       4.0
2020-02-13   1.0       3.0
2020-02-14   1.0       3.0
2020-02-10   2.0       4.0
2020-02-11   2.0       2.0
2020-02-12   2.0       4.0
2020-02-13   2.0       4.0
2020-02-14   2.0       4.0
2020-02-15   2.0       4.0
2020-02-16   2.0       4.0
2020-02-17   2.0       4.0
2020-02-18   2.0       4.0
2020-02-19   2.0       4.0
2020-02-20   2.0       4.0
2020-02-21   2.0       2.0
2020-02-22   2.0       2.0
2020-02-23   2.0       2.0
2020-02-24   2.0       2.0
2020-02-25   2.0       2.0
2020-02-26   2.0       2.0
2020-02-27   2.0       2.0
2020-02-28   2.0       2.0
2020-02-29   2.0       2.0
2020-03-01   2.0       2.0
2020-03-02   2.0       2.0
```

The `resample('D')` does fill in the missing days. Since `key[0]` is the item value for the group the column `item` gets with filled with it. The column `quantity` is filled with `0` for the inserted days.

As `key[1]` is the `lead_time` for the group, `rolling((f'{key[1]}d').sum()` does sum over `lead_time`-many days. Due to the leading `[::-1]` the sumation is done in the right direction (and then readjusted back afterwards).

There's a slight difference to your expected output for `item == 2`, which I can't explain, though?

Comment: Thank you very much! In my first tests, it ran very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I defined the source DataFrame (*df*) with *date* column as *datetime*,
so it contains:

```
   item       date  quantity  lead_time
0     1 2020-02-10         2         14
1     1 2020-02-12         1         14
2     1 2020-02-14         3         14
3     2 2020-02-10         2         20
4     2 2020-02-20         2         20
5     2 2020-03-02         2         20
```

Note that the format of *date* column (when printed) is different from
your source sample (but it may be dependent on the current locale).

First define 2 functions:

1. *myCnt* to count the sum of *quantity* for the given time period:

   ```
   def myCnt(dd, grp, dltDays):
       return grp.loc[dd : dd + pd.Timedelta(dltDays, 'D')].sum()
   ```

   Parameters:

   - *dd* - the start date,
   - *grp* - group of source quantities, but with the index set to the date,
   - *dltDays* - how many days from *dd* is the last date.

   Note that access to the required part of the source group is **by
   the index** (using *loc*), so it should operate quite fast.
2. *itemProc* a function to process the current group of source rows:

   ```
   def itemProc(grp):
       row0 = grp.iloc[0]
       d1 = row0.date
       d2 = grp.date.max() + pd.Timedelta('1D')
       dltDays = row0.lead_time
       grp2 = grp.set_index('date')
       cnt = pd.date_range(d1, d2).to_series().apply(myCnt,
           args=(grp2.quantity, dltDays))
       return pd.DataFrame({'item': row0['item'], 'date': cnt.index, 'quantity': cnt})
   ```

   The parameter is the current group of rows.

   As you didn't define the output date range for each group, I assumed the
   following "border" dates:

   - *start* - the starting date in each group,
   - *end* - the last date in each group + 1 day (for all further,
     dates if you wanted them, the result would contain the *quantity*
     of *0*).

   But if your want another borders of the date, set them according to your
   wish as *d1* and *d2*.

Then, to generate the actual result, it is enough to run a **single** instruction,
i.e. apply this function to each group (grouped by *item*):

```
result = df.groupby('item', as_index=False).apply(itemProc).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result, for your data sample (titled as *Data frame*, not from your code sample), is:

```
    item       date  quantity
0      1 2020-02-10         6
1      1 2020-02-11         4
2      1 2020-02-12         4
3      1 2020-02-13         3
4      1 2020-02-14         3
5      1 2020-02-15         0
6      2 2020-02-10         4
7      2 2020-02-11         4
8      2 2020-02-12         4
9      2 2020-02-13         4
10     2 2020-02-14         4
11     2 2020-02-15         4
12     2 2020-02-16         4
13     2 2020-02-17         4
14     2 2020-02-18         4
15     2 2020-02-19         4
16     2 2020-02-20         4
17     2 2020-02-21         2
18     2 2020-02-22         2
19     2 2020-02-23         2
20     2 2020-02-24         2
21     2 2020-02-25         2
22     2 2020-02-26         2
23     2 2020-02-27         2
24     2 2020-02-28         2
25     2 2020-02-29         2
26     2 2020-03-01         2
27     2 2020-03-02         2
28     2 2020-03-03         0
```

Note that for group with *item == 2* this result is a bit different than
your expected result.

A rationale why **my** result is correct (not yours):

1. For *2020-02-10* the date range is up to *2020-03-01* (including).
   The sum of *quantity* for this period is *4* (for *2020-02-10*
   and *2020-02-20*).
2. For *2020-02-11* the date range is up to *2020-03-02*.
   The sum of *quantity* for this period is **also** *4* (for *2020-02-20*
   and *2020-03-02*).
3. And so on.

Apparently you first created your expected result for smaller *lead_time*
and then, creating the source data sample, you set there *20* days.

Comment: Many thanks! You are right, the period shouldn't include March 2nd.